# Iterating Over the Sobject

Tags: apex, sobject, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

Hi I need to to iterate over the sObject as --> Schema.PicklistEntry  for this i have created the for loop to iterate over it but getting below error, can anyone help me out for this.

```
{`List<Schema.PicklistEntry> aFamily= fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

for(Schema.PicklistEntry ASD: aFamily) {
    if (ASD!= 'BK-AIS') {
        aFamilyList.add(ASD.getValue());
        whereClauseBuilder += 'AND ABC__c = ' + ASD;
     }
  }`}
```

I am getting below error on line if(ASD!='BK-AIS)' can anyone help me out : 
Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.PicklistEntry, String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what is "ASD", ASD is Schema.PicklistEntry. Now you are comparing it with 'BK-AIS' which is string. Which is a problem you can not compare two different types.

So you can compare with any either values:

`if (ASD.getLabel()!= 'BK-AIS')` OR

```
if (ASD.getValue()!= 'BK-AIS')
```